# Django Python Validation

Tags: python, django, validation

we aren't having a common validation issue. The issue we are having is that 0 validation is being checked. As long as the username has input form will submit as it should. We would like to not have the form submit and just display an error message above the field. Here is the code:

### forms.py

```
class register_form(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="Username: ")
    fname = forms.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="First Name: ")
    lname = forms.CharField(max_length=200, help_text="Last Name: ")
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="Email: ")
    remail = forms.CharField(max_length=255, help_text="Re-Type Email: ")
    passwd = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(), max_length=100, help_text="Password: ")
    rpasswd = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(), max_length=100, help_text="Re-Type Password: ")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ()

    def clean_email(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data

        email = cd.get('email')

        if validate_email(email):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please enter a proper email address")
```

### views.py

```
def addUser(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = register_form(request.POST)
        password = request.POST['passwd']
        username = request.POST['username']
        email = request.POST['email']
        objects = UserManager()
        user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)

        if form.is_valid():
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
        else:
            print form.errors
    else:
        form = register_form()
    return render_to_response('testapp/register.html', {'register_form': register_form}, context)
```

### register.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Registration</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <h1>Register with us</h1>

        {% if registered %}
        <a href="/rango/">Return to the homepage.</a><br />
        {% else %}
        <form id="register_form" method="post" action="/testapp/register/"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for hidden in register_form.hidden_fields %}
        {{ hidden }}
            {% endfor %}

            {% for field in register_form.visible_fields %}
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.help_text }}
        {{ field }}
<br>
            {% endfor %}

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
         </form>
         {% endif %}
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Have you considered my question ?

Answer (score 2):

You are using `request.POST` before form validation that's not good. Change your code after `form` `validation` and use `cleaned_data` for processing like

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = register_form(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        password = form.cleaned_data['passwd']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        objects = UserManager()
        user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
else:
    form = reqgister_form()
```

Answer (score 0):

A good practice is to use the CBV

```
class UserCreateView(CreateView):
    def get_form_class(self):
        class _Form(forms.ModelForm):
            passwd = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(), max_length=100, help_text="Password: ")
            rpasswd = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(), max_length=100, help_text="Re-Type Password: ")
            ...

            def clean(self):
                ...

            class Meta:
                fields = ('username', 'email', ...)

        return _Form

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # additional logic
```